# MS SQL Query all table too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, left-join

I'm encoutering a problem with my query. i'm in MS SQL and I try to get all associated table from my patient. From here,everything is going fine. I build up my query first then I execute it. When I execute it, It takes more than 2 min to finish. It's way too long And I have index on all my table. Here's what i try to achieved:

Here's my query build up:

```
  select *  from (          
      select (STUFF((
    SELECT '  ' + AA.LEFTJOIN 
    FROM (Select 'LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + A.name + ' WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = ' + (A.name + '.' + B.Name) + ')' AS LEFTJOIN
             from sysobjects A Join SysColumns B on (A.id = B.id) 
            Where B.name in ('IdPatient','ImageIdPatient')  
            And not A.name in ('tbrv','tbPatient','tbRV_ToExport','tbRV_Archive','tbRV_LOG_Archives','tbPatients_ToExport',
            'tbPatientLock','tbPatient_FusionToExport','tbRV_LOG','tbPatient_A1','tbPatient_A2','tbPatient_A3','tbPatient_QVCDetail') 
            And a.type = 'U' And a.Name LIKE 'tb%') AA
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')
) AS query
union all
 select (STUFF((
    SELECT '  ' + AA.WHERECLAUSE 
    FROM (Select  ' And ' + '(' + A.name + '.' + B.Name + ')  IS NULL '   AS WHERECLAUSE  from sysobjects A Join SysColumns B on (A.id = B.id) 
            Where B.name in ('IdPatient','ImageIdPatient')  
            And not A.name in ('tbrv','tbPatient','tbRV_ToExport','tbRV_Archive','tbRV_LOG_Archives','tbPatients_ToExport',
            'tbPatientLock','tbPatient_FusionToExport','tbRV_LOG','tbPatient_A1','tbPatient_A2','tbPatient_A3','tbPatient_QVCDetail') 
            And a.type = 'U' And a.Name LIKE 'tb%') AA
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')
) AS query ) as AA
```

It's returning:

I add this first in my code :

```
Select  tbPatient.Id, tbPatient.adresse1, tbPatient.nom, tbPatient.prenom From tbPatient " & _
                                         "Left Join tbRV A On (A.Idpatient = tbPatient.ID and A.DateRV >= GETDATE()) " & _
                                         "Left Join tbRV B On ( B.Idpatient = tbPatient.ID and  B.DateRV <= GETDATE() And B.Cloturer = 1)
```

> 

```
 left join tbPatientLettres WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientLettres.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatientprofessionnel WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientprofessionnel.IDPatient)  
left join tbDossierPatient WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbDossierPatient.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_CarnetVacXML WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_CarnetVacXML.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatientDocuments WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientDocuments.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatientAttachements WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientAttachements.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatientMedecins WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientMedecins.IDPatient)  
left join tbNote WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbNote.IdPatient)  
left join tbDossierIntervention WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbDossierIntervention.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatientTaxe WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientTaxe.IdPatient)  
left join tbPatientModeleTaxe WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientModeleTaxe.IdPatient)  
left join tbPTI_Constat_Note_Evolution WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPTI_Constat_Note_Evolution.IDPatient)  
left join tbPTI_Constat_Eval WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPTI_Constat_Eval.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_OrdonnanceEntete WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_OrdonnanceEntete.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_CarnetVac WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_CarnetVac.IDPatient)  
left join tbPTIConstatSuivie WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPTIConstatSuivie.IDPatient)  
left join tbRNIComprimeEntete WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbRNIComprimeEntete.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_QVCEntete WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_QVCEntete.IDPatient)  
left join tbRNITeneursPatient WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbRNITeneursPatient.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_QVCInfirmiere WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_QVCInfirmiere.IDPatient)  
left join tbRNIResultat WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbRNIResultat.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_QVCDestination WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_QVCDestination.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatientRNI WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientRNI.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_CarnetVacRemarque WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_CarnetVacRemarque.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatientImages WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientImages.ImageIDPatient)  
left join tbRVObjetQuestionnaire WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbRVObjetQuestionnaire.IDPatient)  
left join tbPTI_Suivie_CLinique WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPTI_Suivie_CLinique.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_A4 WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_A4.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatientRNIProtocole WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientRNIProtocole.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_D1 WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_D1.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_C1 WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_C1.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatientAssurance WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientAssurance.IdPatient)  
left join tbPatientContacts WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatientContacts.IDPatient)  
left join tbPatient_B1 WITH (NOLOCK) on (tbpatient.Id = tbPatient_B1.IDPatient)
```

I add this clause in my vb code : `where tbpatient.idstatut = 1 And A.Id is NULL And  B.Id is NULL`

```
And (tbPatientLettres.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientprofessionnel.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbDossierPatient.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_CarnetVacXML.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientDocuments.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientAttachements.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientMedecins.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbNote.IdPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbDossierIntervention.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientTaxe.IdPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientModeleTaxe.IdPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPTI_Constat_Note_Evolution.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPTI_Constat_Eval.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_OrdonnanceEntete.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_CarnetVac.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPTIConstatSuivie.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbRNIComprimeEntete.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_QVCEntete.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbRNITeneursPatient.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_QVCInfirmiere.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbRNIResultat.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_QVCDestination.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientRNI.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_CarnetVacRemarque.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientImages.ImageIDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbRVObjetQuestionnaire.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPTI_Suivie_CLinique.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_A4.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientRNIProtocole.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_D1.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_C1.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientAssurance.IdPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatientContacts.IDPatient)  IS NULL    
And (tbPatient_B1.IDPatient)  IS NULL
```

then after that, when i concatenate the two field and executed my query it take more than 2 min... Does someone know how to help things up ? thank you and sorry for the long post.

Comment: "And I have index on all my table. " you by default have indexes on your tables if you have a primary key on it (unless you've removed it).  It might be more important to point out what indexes you have

Comment: Are you missing a "where" in here?  It looks like you're appending all of your ands directly to your join.  Additionally, you're doing a left join, then checking for null - meaning the join did not successfully join?  Wouldn't this query only give you records from the main table, when they don't exist in all other tables you're attempting to join too?

Comment: @Kritner That's exactly what it would do. But I don't really see the purpose of this.

Comment: Slight detour...the NOLOCK hint is almost always a bad decision. Especially in a health care situation like this query appears to be that hint is a really bad choice because the results are not always going to be accurate. You can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows. There are a whole laundry list of other nasty things that can happen using that hint. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: What I really don't understand is why are you using dynamic sql to build a sql statement when you had to hard code the list of tables in the first place and that list is written out twice? Why not just write the query yourself and forget the dynamic sql portion?

Comment: @Radu Gheorghiu I want to get all my patient who didn't come to my clinic

Comment: @Sean Lange The reason why i do that is mainly because i could have add other table in the future.

Comment: @alexandre and you have to check against a lack of record in ***ALL*** of those tables to determine that?

Comment: @alexandre you could also add additional tables to your exclude list... either way you're looking for a code change.

Comment: But if you add another table in the future you have to change the hard coded list so you still have to come back and change your query. Not to mention that if you change the list of tables you would need to include the new columns....unless you are using select *. If that is the case I think we figured out a part of the performance issue.

Comment: @Kritner yes i need to check up all table who contains column Idpatient and yes i would have to change my code if i want to exclude a particular table but that's less jobs that hard code all table i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could simplify things with the below code to get the Patients which have not been to your clinic, and I think it might work better:

```
SELECT Id
FROM tbpatient
EXCEPT
(SELECT IDPatient
FROM tbPatientLettres
UNION
SELECT IDPatient
FROM tbPatientprofessionnel
UNION
SELECT IDPatient
FROM tbDossierPatient
... and so on until you get all your tables in here
)
```

Also, if there is any chance you don't have a non-clustered index on any or some of the `IDPatient` columns, I this should be faster.

Comment: Thank you Very much it's going so much faster now i'll just need to build up this dynamically now :)

Comment: @alexandre I'm glad it was helpful, just out of curiosity, how much faster is it? How long does it take?

Comment: Well, before it was 4 min now it's 4 sec :)